# How do I get the url of uploaded file?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I have uploaded an mp4 file as follows:

```
    import firebase_admin
    from firebase_admin import credentials
    from firebase_admin import storage
    cred = credentials.Certificate('my-app-service.json')
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'storageBucket': 'amy-app-name.appspot.com'
    })

    bucket = storage.bucket()
    blob = bucket.blob('teamfk.mp4')
    blob.upload_from_filename('path/to/teamfk.mp4')
```

Now I can't find the syntax to get a reference to the uploaded url ?

- To add, I should be able to view/download from browser.
- It need not be authenticated, public is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Google Docs - Cloud Storage](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.public_url)

The public URL of the file can be retrieved with

```
blob.make_public()
blob.public_url
```

Comment: Check [make_public](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.make_public)

Comment: +1 to this answer. It seems that the OP likely has ACL permissions on the stored object that prevent direct access. The URL provided by OP in a prior comment includes `&token=...` parameter, which is likely used to authenticate the access request.

Comment: @SpencerD the url is also different, even if I append the same token it doesn't work.`public_url` gives `storage.googleapis.com` but the link on firebase console is `firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b`

Comment: seems token for `storage` is different from `firebasestorage` even though I  am using the same service-account-json. @Vishnudev after making public it works. great. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way! If you want to generate a URL that only valid for a specific time range you can accomplish it using that way.

```
file_url = blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.timedelta(days=1), method='GET') #this URL only valid for 1 day
```

For more details refer [this](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) link :)